# For java.sql.Date AND java.sql.timestamp, can both be converted to datetime in sql server?

Tags: java, sql-server

I have `java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.timestamp` objects in my Java code. I would like to insert them into a SQL Server column. Can this column's datatype be `datetime`?

From this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/how-to/java-to-sql-data-types?view=sql-server-ver15 there are difference between `java.sql.Date` and `timestamp`, but I believe both would convert to datetime. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: The documentation would answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) when you have to deal with only the date part (i.e. year, month and day).
- Use [`java.sql.Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) when you have to deal with both, date and time.